# Fetching IP address of router to which iPhone is connected using Bonjour

Tags: ios, networking, ip-address, router, bonjour

I want to fetch the IP address of router to which my iPhone is currently connected via scanning the MDNS.

I think this can be achievable with Bonjour programming provided by Apple but can't get the proper implementation/guidance.

Can somebody help here with some reference code/documentations/url?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mDNS and routing are completely unrelated systems; mDNS traffic doesn't even get routed.

The only ways I know of to get routing data are to use either sysctl or a routing socket.  And I think only the sysctl works in iOS (because you aren't root), but I'm not certain of that.  See:

[Getting routing table on MACOSX (programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390164/getting-routing-table-on-macosx-programmatically)

And even that will get you only the router's local network address, which may not be what you're looking for, depending on your goals.

Comment: Just to add one minor nit to my answer.  There is one situation where mDNS *might* know about your router.  If the router happens to be an Airport Base Station or Time Capsule, mDNS *may* use that device as a sleep proxy server.  The fact that this happens to be the same device as the router is entirely coincidental, though, and that is not guaranteed.  A Mac with sleep disabled or an Apple TV can also act as the SPS.  As far as I know, there's no way to find out what device is being used as the SPS except by reading through the logs.  Either way, mDNS doesn't care that it's a router, though.